# Using GUID as a Session Key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, guid

Basically I have an object that gets persisted across multiple pages, so I use Session to save and retrieve the object. I'm using a GUID for the Session key. I use a static constructor to create the GUID.

Here is an example of the object:

```
class Customer
{
    private static readonly string _sessionKey;

    public static string SessionKey
    {
        get { return _sessionKey; }
    }

    static Customer()
    {
        _sessionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I use it in my code like this:

```
Session.Add(Customer.SessionKey, new Customer());
```

...

```
Customer C = Session[Customer.SessionKey] as Customer;
```

I personally prefer this method instead of either a `const string` or a `string` literal for the Session key. Just wondering if there any downsides to this or what other approaches have you used?

Comment: It seems like this would make more sense if the key wasn't static, i.e. if there was more than one `Customer` stored in session. Also, this question might be a better fit on http://codereview.statckexchange.com.

Comment: Using a new GUID as a key really falls down if you ever move to a load-balanced environment

Comment: If you're going to store the session key as a static variable, why not just store the `Customer` object as a static variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do this? You should just define constants and be done with it. They aren't descriptive enough if you iterate over or use the debugger with `Session`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have on `Customer` object in session - save under constant name. Otherwise consider saving collection of `Customer` objects under constant name.

Note: if you ever plan to use some other state provider (SQL/state service) instead of default in-memory one make sure your `Customer` object is serializale and makes sense between requests.